# Sencha Touch 2 carousel.setItems() not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to build a dynamic image carousel using Sencha Architect. I have a carousel added to a tab panel. The carousel is set up to read images from a store called "pictureStore." I have a function to pull images from the store and create the carousel items - I can get the images from the store but unable to create the carousel. When I try to use carouself.setItems() or carousel.add() I get an error "Object # has no method". Please take a look and let me know if my method is incorrect for creating a dynamic carousel. I appreciate your help and knowledge of how to fix

Thanks,

Function to read images and create carousel items (works up until comment below):

```
onMycarouselActivate: function(container, newActiveItem, oldActiveItem, options) {
        Ext.getStore('pictureStore').load(function(pictures) {
            var items = [];

            Ext.each(pictures, function(picture) {
                console.log(picture.get('image'));
                if (!picture.get('image')) {
                    return;
                }

                items.push({
                    xtype: 'myimage',
                    picture: picture
                });
            });

            //following doesn't work for adding the carousel images:

            //carousel.setItems(items);
            //carousel.add(items);
            //carousel.items = [{html: items}];
            //carousel.add(carousel.items);
            //carousel.setActiveItem(0);
        });
    },
```

Sample JSON with image info

```
{
    "test": {
        "cat": {
            "entries": [
                {
                    "image": "/images/1.png"
                },
                {
                    "image": "/images/2.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Error messages when using carousel.add or carousel.setItems:

```
Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'add' 
Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'setItems'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `carousel` has no method `add` or `setItems` then it's probably not your carousel.

To make sure of that, you can try to do `console.log(carousel);` to figure out what it is exactly. Also, it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere in your code...

But it's quite simple to fix. I presume you've added a event listener to your carousel that listens to the `activate` event and if you take a look at the [documentation for this event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-event-activate), you can see that the first parameter sent to the callback function is the container (in this case your carousel)

So what you have to write is this :

```
onMycarouselActivate: function(carousel, newActiveItem, oldActiveItem, options) {
```

instead of this

```
onMycarouselActivate: function(container, newActiveItem, oldActiveItem, options) {
```

and you should be all set

**EDIT**

Also if you take a look at the [documentation for the image component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Img), you can see there is no `picture` in the config but there is a `src` attribute. SO you should write :

```
items.push({
  xtype: 'myimage',
  src: picture
});
```

Hope this helped

Comment: when you create the listener through Architect it puts container as first parameter and there does not appear to be a way to change it except though code outside of Architect. I did this and was able to get past the error but the images are still not added to the carousel, although I see the carousel now on the screen. I have followed this example if that helps any http://edspencer.net/2012/02/building-a-data-driven-image-carousel-with-sencha-touch-2.html

Comment: It's just a variable name so if Architect names it 'container' then use container in your code. Also see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I applied your update but still can't get the images appear. I have tried to force an update by calling carousel.doLayout() and Ext.getCmp('carousel').doLayout(); after setItems() but get the error of Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'doLayout'. Am not sure what the issue is

Comment: This function doesn't exist anymore in ST2. Read the documentation before trying something.

Comment: doLayout() has all sorts of rendering time madness, you should try to never use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 myCarousel.add({
                    xtype: 'image',
                    scr:'path of image'
                });
```

where myCarousel is object of carousel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this is working for me:

```
Ext.getStore('Pictures').load(function(pictures) {

        Ext.each(pictures, function(picture) {
            if (picture.get('image')) {
                
                carousel.add({
                        html: '<img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="' + picture.get('image') + '"/>'
                });
            }
        });
 });
```